# Vue devtools in firefox not detecting Vue 3 app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firefox, vuejs3, vue-devtools

Hey guys i'm using **Vue devtools** in **firefox browser**. Vue devtools detecting perfectly on **Vue 2.6.12** application. but it's **not detecting** on **Vue 3.0.0** application.How can solve this problem.
**Thanks**

Comment: This requires to use beta extension release in Chrome. I suppose that's the case for FF either.

Answer (score 3):

There you can install the DevTools for Vue 3, just scroll to `Beta`

https://devtools.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

To install or update the beta version of the devtools, go to one of repository [releases](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/releases) and download the xpi file (https://devtools.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#beta)